# Output printing

Tags: bash, echo

When I use following echo statements I get a nice output which is what expected from such three separate echo statements:

```
echo AP $macaddr
echo noise floor $noise
echo $channel
```

Output:

```
AP ac:67:06:30:eb:00,
noise floor -96
channel=1
```

But when I change all three into one single 'echo' statement like the following, output breaks.

```
echo AP $macaddr noise floor $noise $channel
```

Output:

```
channel=06:30:eb:00, noise floor -96
```

In this output I don't see the channel and MAC Address is missing two of its first octets.
What is causing this? How can avoid this?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Why would `channel` be printed first in your second command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know where channel comes from, but is there a spurious 'CR' at the start of the value of $channel or end $noise?
Try doing:

```
channel=`echo $channel | tr -d '\r'`
noise=`echo $noise | tr -d '\r'`
echo AP $macaddr noise floor $noise $channel
```

...and seeing if that makes a difference. Failing that, see if there's any other dodgy chars in $channel and $noise (and any of the other variables):

```
echo $channel | od -t c
```

and if there are, use `tr -d` to remove them from the variable.

Answer (score 4):

You have a carriage return at the end of `$noise`, so the output `' channel=0'` (note initial space) is overwriting `'AP ac:67:0'`.